# How do I use aio-pika with FastAPI?

Tags: python, asynchronous, fastapi

I want to create a REST service using FastAPI and aio-pika while working asynchronously. For other async database drivers, I could create clients on startup, when get them in route handlers. For example, with motor I would declare simple connection manager:

```
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient


class Database:
    client: AsyncIOMotorClient = None


db = Database()


async def connect_to_mongo():
    db.client = AsyncIOMotorClient("mongo:27017")


async def close_mongo_connection():
    db.client.close()


async def get_mongo_client() -> AsyncIOMotorClient:
    return db.client
```

Then add couple of handlers:

```
app.add_event_handler("startup", connect_to_mongo)
app.add_event_handler("shutdown", close_mongo_connection)
```

and then just use `get_mongo_client` to get one to my handler.

Problem here is that `aio-pika` needs `asyncio` loop to function. Here is an example from the docs:

```
connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(
        "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/", loop=loop
    )
```

And with FastAPI I don't have asyncio loop. Are there any way to use it with interface like in example? Can I just create new loop using `asyncio.get_event_loop()` and pass it to the `connect_robust` without really using it anywhere? Like this:

```
connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(
            "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/", loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
        )
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so, according to the [docs](https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apidoc.html?highlight=connect_robust#aio_pika.connect), I can just use `connect` instead of `connect_robust`:

```
connection = await aio_pika.connect(
        "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/"
    )
```